# Handling HTTP 302 Moved Temporarily requests in netty

Tags: redirect, netty, http-status-code-302

I am using netty http client to fetch urls using netty. However, for some urls which are redirecting to some other page, I am unable to fetch the content of the final page using my client. I want to know how to handle 302 redirects in my response handler.

Below is the code used in messageReceived function of my response handler.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        if (!readingChunks) {
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) e.getMessage();

            System.out.println("STATUS: " + response.getStatus());
            System.out.println("VERSION: " + response.getProtocolVersion());
            System.out.println();

            if (!response.getHeaderNames().isEmpty()) {
                for (String name: response.getHeaderNames()) {
                    for (String value: response.getHeaders(name)) {
                        System.out.println("HEADER: " + name + " = " + value);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            if (response.isChunked()) {
                readingChunks = true;
                System.out.println("CHUNKED CONTENT {");
            } else {
                ChannelBuffer content = response.getContent();
                if (content.readable()) {
                    System.out.println("CONTENT {");
                    System.out.println(content.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
                    System.out.println("} END OF CONTENT");
                }
            }
        } else {
            HttpChunk chunk = (HttpChunk) e.getMessage();
            if (chunk.isLast()) {
                readingChunks = false;
                System.out.println("} END OF CHUNKED CONTENT");
            } else {
                System.out.print(chunk.getContent().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code.. without it it will impossible to help.

Comment: Did you expect Netty to handle the redirect for you?

Comment: I want to know how to handle redirects using netty. I couldn't find anything regarding this on the web. So posting here. I have used the code given in snoop example given as a part of netty. I used the same netty client for fetching.

Comment: This is the code used in messageReceived function of my response handler.